# rebalancing binary search tree

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-search-tree

update 11:15 pm est 4/29/15 --

thanks guys it helped a lot, almost there....

```
 public BinarySearchTree<AnyType> rebalanceHelp(ArrayList<AnyType> nl){
 BinarySearchTree<AnyType> p = new BinarySearchTree<AnyType>();
 //base case, if theres two elements in the list,   
 if(nl.size() == 2){p.insert(nl.get(0));p.insert(nl.get(1));}
  ArrayList<AnyType> left = new ArrayList<AnyType>();
  ArrayList<AnyType> right = new ArrayList<AnyType>();
  p.insert(nl.get(nl.size()/2));
  //loops through first half of the arraylist putting each element into a new arraylist, left
  for(int i = 1; i < ((nl.size()/2)-1); i++){
  left.add(nl.get(i));

  }
  //loops through second half of the arraylist putting each element into a new arraylist, right
  for(int j = nl.size()-1; j > ((nl.size()/2)+1); j--){
  right.add(nl.get(j));

  }
  //recursivley calls on left and right
  rebalanceHelp(left);rebalanceHelp(right);
      return p;
  }


public void rebalance(){
  //need a list of some sort (l) that i can resize and add to even if it is full 

  ArrayList<AnyType> l = new ArrayList<AnyType>();
  //ArrayList<AnyType> nl = new ArrayList<AnyType>();

  while(this.isEmpty() != true){
    l.add(this.findMin());
    this.removeMin();
   }
  this.rebalanceHelp(l);
}
```

now getting error:

```
DuplicateItemException: 8
at BinarySearchTree.insert(BinarySearchTree.java:171)
at BinarySearchTree.insert(BinarySearchTree.java:169)
at BinarySearchTree.insert(BinarySearchTree.java:78)
at BinarySearchTree.rebalanceHelp(BinarySearchTree.java:46)
at BinarySearchTree.rebalanceHelp(BinarySearchTree.java:58)
at BinarySearchTree.rebalanceHelp(BinarySearchTree.java:58)
at BinarySearchTree.rebalanceHelp(BinarySearchTree.java:58)
at BinarySearchTree.rebalance(BinarySearchTree.java:73)
at BinarySearchTree.main(BinarySearchTree.java:337)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)
```

the problem lies in my for loops in my recursive method, any help on these will be great, the last few answers gave me a lot of insight and understanding. 
thanks, matt

Comment: It makes it much easier to help if you actually include the error and a stack trace.

Comment: The method you have described is known as partitioning. But this should only be done for items that are not sorted. You have already sorted the array, so why are you recursing so much? A simple for-loop could solve this

Comment: So, it doesn't appear that you ever actually place the trees you build back into the tree you return.  Also, what's the array you're inputing?

Answer (score 0):

That is not how you typically balance a BST.  When a BST is not balanced you fix it by rotating nodes.  This is a link to code that takes care of it.  http://users.cis.fiu.edu/~weiss/dsaajava3/code/AvlTree.java

Comment: helpful, thanks, but i think i want to stick with this less effective way of doing it.(just to prove to myself i can do it) because i know it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

So, as Scott said, this is a pretty terrible way to do this, and if you want to learn how to build a balanced BST yourself, I would suggest that you look up Red-Black trees, as these are the easiest for someone relatively unfamiliar with BSTs to code.

That being said, the problem in your code here is pretty simple, its actually an array one.  Recall that in Java (as in most languages) arrays are 0 indexed.  This means that in a 50 element array, element 49 is actually the last element, if you try to access element 50, you will receive an exception.  So your problem is here:

```
for(int j = nl.size(); j > ((nl.size()/2)); j--)
{
    right.add(nl.get(j));
}
```

Your fix is this:

```
for(int j = nl.size()-1; j > ((nl.size()/2)); j--)
{
    right.add(nl.get(j));
}
```

Unfortunately, you don't have line numbers here, so I am not completely certain this is the fix.